# Symfony Form Entity ManyToMany

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity Skill and ManyToMany Language and I need create form and in this form add name language for skill, now I add 'multiple'=>true, in form and have many language but when $form->isValid() I have error

```
This value is not valid.
```

in form

```
invalidValue={array}[2]
   0 = "Java"
   1 = "PHP"
```

Why in not valid I not understand ??

rhis is my entity skill

```
class Skill
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="skill", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $skill;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills")
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->language = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->platforms = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->specialities = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add language
 *
 * @param \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages $language
 *
 * @return Skill
 */
public function addLanguage(\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages $language)
{
    $this->language[] = $language;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove language
 *
 * @param \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages $language
 */
public function removeLanguage(\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages $language)
{
    $this->language->removeElement($language);
}

/**
 * Get language
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getLanguage()
{
    return $this->language;
}
```

this is my form

```
class SkillType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('mainSkill','checkbox');
            $builder->add('language','entity',
                array(
                    'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                    'property'=>'languages', )
            );
    $builder
    ->add('edit','submit')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'skill';
}
}
```

and my action when $form->submit($request); have this error

```
/**
 * Edit skill.
 *
 * @Route("/skills/edit/{id}", name="skill_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="MyBundle:Skill")
 */
public function editSkillsAction(Request $request, $entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SkillType(), $entity);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('skills_show'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'debug' => true,
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**
I try to add in form 'expanded' => true, and everything work, doctrine create ManyToMany relation in table. Maybe is there another way ?

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('mainSkill','checkbox');
            $builder->add('language','entity',
                array(
                    'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages',
                    'property'=>'languages',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                     )
            );
    $builder
    ->add('edit','submit')
    ;
}
```